# Bukkit Chat Clickable Buttons

Tags: java, chat, minecraft, bukkit

I'm actually coding a plugin, in a command it prompts a confirmation message and I want to click a button (on the chat text) for confirming and cancellating. I don't like to copying and pasting code from others, and I don't want to use classes from others too.
I am trying to use TextComponents but I can't make it work. Here is the command code

```
package myPackage;

import java.awt.TextComponent;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class InfoCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    public TextComponent TextComponent;
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmnd, String alias, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            return false;
        }
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(new String[] {
                            "Confirmation message.",
                            "Do you want to confirm?"});
        TextComponent message = new TextComponent ("Yes");
        message.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "/command"));
        return true;
    }            
}
```

It trows me 3 errors:

`TextComponent(String) is not public in TextComponent; cannot be accesed from outside package` (In the line where I define TextComponent)

`Cannot find symbol` (In the ClickEvent line)

`Package ClickEvent does not exist` (In the ClickEvent line)

How can I solve the errors? There is an easier way to do a clickable buttons (without other classes or copying/pasting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1. You're missing a dependency. Add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version><!--change this value depending on the version-->
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. You have imported `java.awt.TextComponent` in your `InfoCommand`  class, which is wrong. So remove that import and add these instead:

```
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.ClickEvent;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.TextComponent;
```

Comment: I'm not using Maven, do I have to put something on the Libraries section of my project in the IDE instead?

Comment: When using external libraries, it is often a good idea to use Maven. However, you can download the JAR from https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.12.2-R0.1-20180712.012057-156.jar and put it in your libraries directory.

Comment: I added the version I needed to my Libraries and imported what you said. But stills trowing the `Package does not exist` error.

Comment: That's why not using Maven tends to be annoying. Other dependencies aren't automatically resolved. The last thing missing should be:  https://repo.acrylicstyle.xyz/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.12-SNAPSHOT/bungeecord-chat-1.12-20180712.114550-97.jar

Comment: Thanks, it worked! For the next time I will try to use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the system currently built into spigot. You should be using [Kyori/adventure](https://docs.adventure.kyori.net/index.html). Its much better, and paper is going to implement it natively soon.

A solution using `adventure`:

```
Component.text("My Clickable Text").color(NamedTextColor.GREEN).clickEvent(new ClickEvent(<paramaters>)
```